# Is there a way to share a file with an http link (not https)?

Tags: html, file, share, file-sharing, fileshare

I need to share a link so when people get connected to a server on a game, they can download online the mod file quickly.
Unfortunately, the game doesn't support https url so doesn't support any google drive, Mega, Dropbox or Mediafire link.
I've searched how to make a server but every free server doesn't support the uploading of a file who is more than 10mb (mine is 100).
Do someone have a free solution ?

Thank you

Comment: What game is auto-downloading mods over an unencrypted connection in 2022? That's just a recipe for disaster, for so many reasons.

Comment: Quake3, not quite 2022 lol